# Saving a record with hasMany and server sending partial data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to save a new record with hasMany relationship. All the records, the parent and the child records wont have ids initially. The server will send only the ids for all records instead of full payload.

The parent record gets the data as expected. But a copy of child record is created. One has id and nothing else. The other has all the original data and no id. My guess is ember data cannot associate the record returned by server to the existing record.

I added ids to child records just to check. Now there are no copies. But the child records are still marked as dirty.

Before the 1.0.0-beta.14 i used to create a backup of the record before saving. It was pretty ugly.

What i want to achieve,

1. Save hasMany relationship records when the parent record is saved.
2. Server will send only autogenerated ids for both parent and child records.
3. Ember Data should automatically associate the returned child record to the one in the parent record before saving and mark isDirty as false.

Here is a sample jsbin
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dowije/1/